# Is there any way to resize a web page for a lower resolution than it was designed for?

Tags: html, css

I've been asked to see if I can solve this issue. Another dev wrote the page, using a mishmash of percentages and px values for margins, padding, dimensions etc. These values are sprinkled both inline and in the css file. It was meant to be deployed on a set of tablets with a 1920x1080 resolution. However, the actual devices are running 1024x600. As you can guess, this has thrown everything out of whack. As of now, I'm guessing I'll be spending the next few hours changing the values to percentages. Is there any other way to do this?

To clarify, I don't need to make it responsive. This is a page that would *only* be viewed on a 1920x1080 screen but now will *only* be viewed on a 1024x600 screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very 'hacky' solution, but what finally worked was creating a new web page containing nothing but an iframe hardcoded with the original resolution settings (inline CSS height and width). The content of that iframe is the page that was to be resized. This entire thing was then imported into android studio and then exported as an apk. When that apk was installed and run, it worked. I'm not sure why, but it did work, so we left it at that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little dirty, but it will work:

```
html {
    zoom:0.5;
}
```

your webpage will be zoomed to 50%. You can add **media-queries** so it only uses the zoom on specific screen widths

Comment: That doesn't work, unfortunately. Anything that uses px instead of % doesn't seem to be affected. I've also tried using transform, and that doesn't do the job either.

Comment: does your code use meta viewport? something like this: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Nope. It's a very simple page. It has no meta tags apart from a charset and no media queries either. The guy who wrote it is very bad at this. The page has basically been shoehorned to fit the original resolution spec by hardcoding margins to get images/text to be shown outside of the bounds of their parent divs.